# Unable to open URL with xdg-open

Tags: url, xdg-open

Getting this error as regular user:

```
~$ xdg-open http://www.google.com/
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://www.google.com/'
~$
~$ xdg-mime query default text/html
~$
```

Code from /usr/bin/xdg-open

```
  # if BROWSER variable is not set, check some well known browsers instead
    if [ x"$BROWSER" = x"chromium" ]; then
        BROWSER=links2:elinks:links:lynx:w3m
        if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
            BROWSER=firefox:mozilla:epiphany:konqueror:chromium:google-chrome:$BROW$
        fi
    fi

    open_envvar "$1"

    exit_failure_operation_impossible "no method available for opening '$1'"
}
```

---

Operating system: Ubuntu 16.04 Gnu/Linux

Comment: Why are you doing this as root? Does it work as expected if you do it as a regular user? You say "code modified", what code? Where? How did you modify it?

Comment: It didnt work as a regular user

Comment: OK, then please [edit] your question and show what happens when you do it as a regular user instead of root since root is a very special case. And please also explain what the code you are showing is, where it is from, why it is relevant and how you changed it.

Comment: Also, what is the output of `xdg-mime query default text/html` and what browsers do you have installed? Is this Ubuntu server? Do you have a working graphical environment?

Answer (score 0):

The MIME type xdg-open uses for URIs is `x-scheme-handler/<scheme>`, in your case `x-scheme-handler/http` and `x-scheme-handler/https`. You can put an entry for those using your desired .desktop file in your

```
${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/mimeapps.list
```

file.